# How to avoid touch in certain regions of a custom view?

Tags: ios

In my custom View which I have added to my viewControllers's view, I need to handle touches but only in certain regions of it and not everywhere.

How do I go about it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `pointInside:withEvent:` to make the view ignore touches that aren't in the region you want.